# Asp.net: compare string text and database table?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table in access database that contains **Names** and I have a `Textbox` that contain text.

I would like to write a code in asp.net to compare each word in the `Textbox` to the table in database to know if this `Textbox` contain a name and display this name found in another `Textbox`?

Comment: Have you done any development in ASP.NET before?  If not, you may want to go through some tutorials to help get you started.

Comment: i have the function that fill the values in the database table in a data table.

but how to compare these values to each word in a textbox ??

Comment: Please show what code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

The following would be in a loop if you're checking against every record in the table:

```
DataTable dt; // already populated

if(txtBox.Text.Trim() == dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString())
{
    otherTxtBox.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
}
```

Not sure by your question if one "of each" word in a text box could find a match in the DB field? If so, then you need to parse each word first and do a compare on that.

Comment: yes i need to parse each word and then do a compare..
please i would like to know how o do that ??
@IrishChieftain

Comment: Not going to code it for you. Simple Google search yielded this: http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/230508/Split-Text-from-TextBox-to-get-words-and-store-them-in-Database-using-C-ASPNet/